# Win10 install media with multiple product keys

Tags: windows-10, installation

I see this post that may be my answer, but wanted to verify with the community for Win10 USB. ([Can I use multiple product keys with the same Win 7 DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/128979/can-i-use-multiple-product-keys-with-the-same-win-7-dvd))

I am upgrading my existing computer from Win7 Home to Win10 Home, and then wish to do a clean install.  I know I can use my Win7 product key for the re-install, so no problem there.
I'm also building a new computer, and am buying the Win10 Home USB stick for this machine.

My question is, can I use that stick to install on the new computer, using the accompanying product key, *and then also* use that stick for the old computer's clean re-install, using the old computer's product key?  Does it matter that the USB stick is retail, and the old computer is OEM?

Comment: For whomever down voted, if that was based on supposed 'lack of research', then I'll respectfully disagree.  The accepted answer below is in direct disagreement with what I was told by the company that sold me the install media.  According to them, the product key is indeed tied to the USB.  And in any case, I quoted another post as a show of good faith that I had done research.

Comment: I think you meant 'are _not_ worded very well', so your point is well taken.

Comment: It was sufficiently clear for the answering user below.  Comparing my post to your first comment, I think I know where the lack of understanding lies.

Comment: So you care enough about a downvote to complain about but not enough, to make an edit to the question, so the mistaken vote can be retracted.  If an edit is made to the question, I will be able to reverse my vote, otherwise that cannot happen.  *I will be removing my comments since they are obsolete.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you explicitly include some unattended installation script or otherwise modify it, all Windows media are identical. Of course, there are still various versions like Home, Pro, Enterprise and whatnot. However, multiple copies of each are just that: Exact copies.

This hasn’t changed with Windows 10. So yes, you can use the same DVD/USB drive to install Windows on many PCs using many keys.

You don’t need a key at all when reinstalling Windows 10 on a PC that already had Windows 10, by the way. It’ll automatically obtain the previous activation from Microsoft and continue using it. You also don’t need to upgrade first, because Windows 10 1151 can be activated directly using an eligible key for previous Windows versions.

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I've read about the 1151 detail you mention, but had read also about the need to first upgrade to activate that key with Win10.  Thanks for clearing up that confusion.
I didn't realize that the key wasn't necessary on a re-install.  Very nice that, too.

Comment: 'but had read also about the need to first upgrade to activate that key with Win10. " - This is not correct.

Comment: I doubt this answer is precisely correct. For earlier Windows versions you always need the specific OEM source for the OEM keys ( I mean those from vendors like HP or so, not those you can buy for custom builds). When the "with Bing" thing comes up, you need the "with Bing" source, which is not public available at all. But with Windows 10 things seem to be really "general" now.

Comment: The author is not using a specialize installation like `w/Bing` or `Single Language` so any version of Windows 10 installation media will work.  Version 1511 even combined the Home and Professional, and Microsoft also, freely offers the other versions for download at the same source website.  **In relation to Windows 10, which this question is about, this answer is indeed correct.**  Even in relation to Windows 7 media it is correct.